# How to use dhcpd on two network interfaces?

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, dhcp, arm

I have an embedded system that has Ethernet and wifi. I want to setit up in a way that it provides IP to both interfaces. The system uses BusyBox. and I an new in this area.

can you provide a sample configuration that I can run to setup dhcpd for both of these interfaces?

Should I run two instance of dhcpd to do this?

The Linux is based on TI EZSDK ( for arm processors)

Comment: indeed, you should start two instances of dhcpd  
you can use [ https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Configuring_a_Multihomed_DHCP_Server.html ] as a start point and adapt it to your dhcpd server

Comment: openWRT is a router-specific very light distribution based on busybox. If you just want to setup a router maybe you can try it. You can find it here: https://openwrt.org/ . I use it at home for my wifi/eth router, and it work really well.

Comment: @vasily-vm No, you do not need two instances of dhcpd, you simply need two subnet declarations in /etc/dhcp/dhcpd - as given in the link you mention.